# Minimizar aplicacion de cordova con Javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

Tengo una app que se cierra al presionar el boton backbutton, lo que quiero hacer es que al presionar dicho boton esta aplicacion se minimize en lugar de cerrarse, como puedo realizar dicha tarea?

Comment: Hola Agustin, aunque esta pregunta puede ser buena para el sitio, se ha marcado como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor edítala para añadir más detalles (p.e. ¿cómo gestionas el back button? ¿cuál es el código que tienes? etc)

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]